# Wordpress, change language_attributes to return dir=rtl

Tags: wordpress, hebrew, right-to-left

In wordpress, inside the header.php file of a theme, there is the next line:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
```

By default, it(`language_attributes`) returns `dir=ltr`, and every online guide i read tried to show a way to hange the css file.

it's not enough and not semantic. i need to change the html itself to rtl.
how can it be done?
is there a settings file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to edit your default language is through the wp-config.php file on the root directory.

This case should be for Spanish of Spain
define ('WPLANG', 'es_ES');

This one to the USA English
define ('WPLANG', 'en_US');

You have all the possible combinations at this page:
http://xml.coverpages.org/iso639a.html

Regards

Comment: This won't fix the issue if you don't download the rtl language file. See @nightS answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can control the text direction via the language files. If you download the Arabic(an RTL langauge) [Wordpress](http://ar.wordpress.org/) for example.
You'll find this value is set in the \wp-content\languages\ar.php as:

```
$text_direction = 'rtl';
```

And to enable it..you need to set the WPLANG variable in your wp-config to the RTL language like this:

```
define ('WPLANG', 'ar');
```

Then your language_attributes() will output the dir='rtl' you want.

Comment: That's the completely correct answer. I tested right now. If you want to have your dashboard in english and just the template in arabic, then it's enough if you copy `wp-content/languages/ar.php` from arabic wordpress package to your `wp-content/languages/` directory (you can create if it doesn't exist). And of course, change language definition in `wp-config.php` as told

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the following two links. You need to ensure both of your theme and WordPress are setup for RTL.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Right_to_Left_Language_Support

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_bloginfo

Comment: Doesn't seem to be this easy :) The CSS method is what the OP already has (but doesn't want);  `get_bloginfo()` is deprecated in 3.0 in favour of `is_rtl()` which is defined [here](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/wp-includes/locale.php#L346), but I have no idea where this is changed

Comment: I provided the second link to show the blog info options that need to be set. The OP didn't mention trying that. I believe the combination of the two should get it done as the WP Codex is reliable, albeit sometimes dated.

Comment: thanks guys, but it seems that my main problem with WP still stands. get_blohinfo() and other functions are getters, where and how I use  the setters?

As to the original question, i found the answer by crawling in the files. there is the locale.php file under wp-include, there's a global var named $text_direction, the is_rtl uses it.

And, o/c - it's wp3.
thanks again

Comment: I would see if this variable is set in the database. Hence the `get_bloginfo()` reference. That way you're not hardcoding it in the core files.